# Console not ready ruby sublime text file

Tags: ruby, macos, console, sublimetext2

I'm new to programming.  Just about to start learning Ruby.  I already took a console class, but I am stuck here.

I'm using a mac 10.6.8. I have done a quick 1+2 in the sublime text editor.  I saved it.  I went over to my console typed irb and then typed ruby example.rb.  I have read elsewhere here that typing require './example' would help....it didn't.  I am getting the following

```
NameError: undefined local variable or method `example' for main:Object
from (irb):2
from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/bin/irb:16:in `<main>'
```

I don't understand what I am doing wrong.  Thank you for your help.  I really appreciate it.

-L

Comment: From the console, type 'ruby example.rb', where example.rb contains only 'puts 1+2' and you should see the output.

Answer (score 0):

I would do as below:

```
kirti@kirti-Aspire-5733Z:~$ irb
2.0.0p0 :001 > require 'fileutils'
 => true 
2.0.0p0 :002 > FileUtils.pwd
 => "/home/kirti" 
2.0.0p0 :003 > FileUtils.cd "/home/kirti/ruby" 
 => nil 
2.0.0p0 :004 > load "./SO.rb"
3
 => true 
2.0.0p0 :005 > require "./SO.rb"
3
 => true
```

My `SO.rb` file contains the below line :

```
puts 1+2
```

Comment: I typed everything. When I typed in "home/jazzlark/ruby" and pressed enter nothing came out. Not even nil....I kept going anyway and...nothing happened. ;(  Thanks for your help anyway.

Answer (score 0):

May be you wanna give a try.
Step 1: Navigate to your project/file folder by using command "cd folder_name/folder_location"
Step 2: load './example.rb'

For better solution you may wanna define some function inside example.rb 
Like:

```
def sum  
   1 + 2  
end
```

And to get the output enter **sum** in irb after loading the **example.rb** file.

Comment: All of that I did and nothing helped.  Thank you! ;(  I am trying to get the console to see what the sublime text editor is doing.  That is my main objective.

Comment: @jazzlark You mean, u r not getting your output as 3? btw sublime editor has nothing to do with irb/ruby/rails or anything. it only helps you in creating/editing files. So, in your case it will do nothing.

Comment: thank you....I'm following a book called "Learn To Program" and I am following directions.  So I don't know why the book would steer me wrong.

Answer (score 0):

irb is the interactive ruby shell. Within the shell, everything you type is interpreted as Ruby code, not bash commands. So, for example:

```
bash> puts 1 + 2
# command not found: puts
# this happens because you're not in a Ruby shell

bash> irb
# now you're in a Ruby shell
irb> puts 1 + 2
# 3
```

If you wrote some code in `example.rb`, you have two options:

1. From the **bash** shell, run `ruby example.rb` (from the same directory where your `example.rb` file is saved.
2. From the **irb** console, you can `require 'example'`, which will load the contents of `example.rb` into your interpreter. In this case, it will immediately execute the Ruby code. If you wrapped the contents of `example.rb` in a class, it would load the class, but not execute code within it until you instantiated/called it.

Hopefully that helps!

Comment: My main objective is for the console to see what the sublime text editor is doing. putting 1 + 2 in the console comes out 3 in the console easy. Thank you!

Comment: No problem! Just make sure that you understand the 3 different concepts in play: (1) bash (aka terminal) (2) irb (the ruby interpreter) and (3) Sublime Text (text editor). You'll need to become very familiar with these 3 things to be successful!

Comment: Kyle, I understand all 3, but I don't understand why the console is not seeing the sublime 'puts 1 + 2' when I type in the console irb and then ruby example.rb.  Understand?

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you are typing (into irb):

```
require example.rb
```

When you need to type:

```
require './example.rb'
```

The first tells ruby: "require what is in a variable called example". Because you did not define a variable called example, it results in the no variable or method error.

The second tells ruby: "require a string './example.rb'". Since the require method essentially knows how to find the file name passed as a string and evaluate the file, you'll get the right output

By the way, for this example, example.rb needs to be in the same directory. If example.rb is in another directory, you'll need to use the full path (I won't expand on it here) to source it.

You'll also notice that the output will look something like this:

```
    3
    => true
```

This is because the file was evaluated (executing the code: `puts 1+2`) and the `require` method returns `true` to indicate it evaluated the file.

If you require the file again, you'll get `false` because the file is already loaded.